# Unclear idea prove the union of the images of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

$$f^{-1}\big( \bigcup_{\alpha \in a} E_{\alpha}\big) = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$$

Reasoning: the left side is the output of the inverse. Meaning that x is the output for a $y \in E_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in A$ which means that $y$ is an element of $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}f^{-1}E_{\alpha}$ Am I on the right track? can someone break this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that in a general sense: $$x\in f^{-1}(E)\iff f(x)\in E$$

So the following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}\right)$
- $f(x)\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}$
- $\exists\alpha\in A\;\left[f(x)\in E_{\alpha}\right]$
- $\exists\alpha\in A\;\left[x\in f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})\right]$
- $x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$

Looking at the first and last bullet we conclude that:$$f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}\right)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$$